# grub-install: error: cannot find efi directory

Tags: kali-linux, grub, boot-loader

I recently dual-boot **kali-linux-2016.2-amd64** with windows 10. After sometime I updated my windows 10 and due to this windows might have removed grub from the boot menu. Now I can't boot kali-linux from the boot menu because it doesn't appear there anymore.

So I decided to re-install grub by booting into Live-kali(Persistent) from USB. I entered the following command in the terminal:

```
fdisk -l
sudo mount /dev/sda* /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
sudo chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
```

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

```
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt
```

After the 7th command-line I got this error:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very hard to help you because you don't know basic commands... but I'll try okay?

- With `fdisk -l` you list your current partition, like your image.
- With your image I can see that you have /dev/sda1 as EFI System, /dev/sda10 as Linux filesystem and /dev/sda11 as Linux swap. Keep this information.
- When you boot with a live cd you must do a `chroot` for access your system, in other words, an operation that changes the apparent root directory for the current running process and its children. Lets go:
- mount your system at /mnt. Remember? Linux filesystem? Yes. It's /dev/sda10. So do command:

          
  `sudo mount /dev/sda10 /mnt`.

  *You are using `sudo` because you must have administrator permissions to do it.*
- So, mount the temporary filesystems needed for programs work, with the commands:

          
  `sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev`
          
  `sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts`
          
  `sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc`
          
  `sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys`
- You are modifying your boot, so you need your /boot partition too. Some systems uses the same partition for the /boot directory and system root (/). If you don't know what is your case, so at this point check if you have files in the folder /mnt/boot/ (you will find your kernel images, configurations , etc).

     - *If the /mnt/boot folder is empty, so you need mount the /boot partition. The only other possibly usable partition on your case is /dev/sda1, so will be it. Mount at /mnt/boot.*  
     - *If you found the files, so the another partition at /dev/sda1 should be really the EFI Filesystem, and it must be mounted at /mnt/boot/EFI.*
- With all mounted,change root directory using:

          
  `sudo chroot /mnt /bin/bash`
- Now, inside chroot, you can install grub:

  `sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: I've added for you.

Comment: I've add some info... You got now?

Comment: Finally I'm able to install grub and now I can run kali. Using your excellent answer I did a work around. Remember your earlier answer ` $ sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi`. I inserted this command-line between the 5th & the 6th command. If I had carefully examined your previous edit I would've solved my problem earlier.

Comment: Thank you a lot @LaraMaia and defalt ! I've basically fixed grub by combining this answer with `grub-install --recheck /dev/sdX` and `grub-update` commands. All working now :) (commands copied from this post https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)