# Ubuntu UEFI entry point missing

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, uefi, boot-loader

I originally had Ubuntu 20.10 installed on my HDD without any booting problem. Days ago my HDD broke down and I decided to migrate to a new SSD. I installed Ubuntu 20.10 on the SSD just like before, but was unable to find any UEFI entry after reboot.

I followed [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320014/grub-install-error-cannot-find-efi-directory) post together with [this](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd) tutorial and managed to recover an entry using a Live USB (`sudo efibootmgr -v` displays an `Ubuntu` entry). However, after rebooting the PC the entry was still missing, and the `Ubuntu` entry seemed to have disappeared from `sudo efibootmgr -v`.

- OS: Ubuntu 20.10
- Motherboard: Asrock Z97 Extreme6
- SSD: Western Digital SN550

Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: UEFI would keep old entry, which then would be invalid until new install over wrote it. Did you reinstall in UEFI boot mode & let grub install to ESP? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair